# How to stop periodic location updates when driver goes out of vehicle?

Tags: android, geolocation

In a truck, there is an app running on a tablet that records location every 60 seconds.

I need to stop periodic recording of the location, once the truck ends its driving, so further movement of the tablet is not considered part of the route.

E.g. after end of driving, it is possible that the driver walks with the tablet around town.

My ideas for solving this are:

1. A button driver has to press when he ends driving to stop recording - easy to implement, but there is the risk driver forgets pressing the button
2. Checking difference between current and previous location - e.g. when distance in meters didn't change by more than 20 meters in few minutes the vehicle will be considered stopped. Of course there's the risk that vehicle is in traffic jam
3. Use activity recognition from Google Services - use this mechanism to check the activity and once I get other activity (with high enough confidence), I stop the recording

**What way would you suggest for this?**

Comment: Is it possible to require the application being charged when in Car ? Then you could make some nice once the charger is unplugged to get the drivers attention to maybe stop the location updates..

Comment: This is interesting idea. I'll check if there will be a dock station available. If so, I could monitor the current docking state (and type), and start/stop recording of position based on this state.

Comment: I suppose also in docking station the device would be not rotated etc., so you could also maybe use sensors for detecting the removal of the device of any docking station.

Answer (score 1):

> A button driver has to press when he ends driving to stop recording - easy to implement, but there is the risk driver forgets pressing the button

I agree with you, is too dangerous let deciding to user for the action of the app

> Checking difference between current and previous location - e.g. when distance in meters didn't change by more than 20 meters in few minutes the vehicle will be considered stopped. Of course there's the risk that vehicle is in traffic jam

In my opinion this alghoritm is not efficient; it would be better checking changes not on meters, 'cause the GPS sensor have alsways some errors during sensing, so you should check if the changes in meters has been changed in a value more than the error (accuracy value); in that case you are quite sure something has been changed or not

> Use activity recognition from Google Services - use this mechanism to check the activity and once I get other activity (with high enough confidence), I stop the recording

This would be very intresting, but should be tested;

However there are a fourth case: using another device (like driver personal smartphone) connected via Bluetooth to the device where App is recordind GPS Data and when the driver let the car the devices will lost the BT connection, so this trigger could be caught from the GPS App and that case stopping the data recording